# Is it possible to run node js apps as a background service on android?

Tags: android, node.js, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms application that uses a node.js server as a local background service, It's working fine on the UWP version (I compiled the node app as a .exe using pkg), so I was wondering if it's possible to do the same on android.

I've been searching and I've found node-on-android(https://github.com/node-on-mobile/node-on-android), but apparently it builds a complete app, including a frontend with a webview

I would like to know if it is possible to extract that background from the built app or create my own service and run it.

Comment: The real question here is not so much if it is possible but "is this a good way to proceed?".

Comment: @Henry My proyect is an app that searches for torrents on a web and downloads them. I'm trying to add torrent managenent, but since UWP has so many restrictions regarding file access I'm using WebTorrent on node. Thera are probably many other ways, but I have 3 weeks left to finish it (since It's for my graduation proyect) and, If possible, I would like to add the torrent management on part on android